# connect/link multiple plots interactively in python

Tags: python, pandas, visualization, crossfilter

I am trying to explore a `multi-variable` dataset in `python pandas` using `jupyter notebook`. Given that my data-set has multiple variables I want to explore relationships across variables. For example:

- Plot variable A - any type of plot (i.e. Histogram).
- Given a selection of region/slice of the histogram of variable A, I want to see what variables B, C and D look like (in any type of plot).
- As well, I'd like the ability to select regions/slices of any one of variables B, C or D and see what the other variables look like.

So far I've only found [crossfilter](http://square.github.io/crossfilter/), which is a javascript library. Is there any such solution that works well with pandas dataframes?

I think most applications would require something like the functionality I am seeking.

What do people use to achieve this?

To date crossfilter is the only solution?

Comment: Are you looking for a GUI solution, i.e. interactive plots, or code examples for slicing and plotting the data?

Comment: gui. Any static solution really has no value. To re-draw/plot static plots every time you change/slide variables value to see the effect on other variables would make it a non-useable solution. The solution has to be visually interactive.

Comment: Try bokeh: http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/